# Sharepoint Permissions Shared with

Tags: sharepoint

When someone shares a document but doesn't include the owner (I am the owner) I can't see it! This is a big problem because if someone publish different documents but only he and his group can see it, if they leave the company how can I find this documents??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If someone shares a document exclude the file owner, the file owner will not see the document. It's by design.

As a workaround, you could set the file owner as the site collection administrator. Even if someone shares a document exclude the file owner, the file owner can also see the document.

Update:

1.Click site permissions in the site settings.

[image]

2.Advanced permission settings -> Site Collection Administrators.
[image]
[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for replying me.. Please could you specify the step to do this? I'm not very familiar with sharepoint but I have to work with this for the company where I work

Comment: Thank you for the update, I'm glad you're helping me out. But I still have problems.. The network I use from the company doesn't let me open the images.. I tryed to go to site permissions but I can't see any "Advanced permission settings". Where do I find it?

Comment: I found a way to see the images.. Now I can tell you that I don't have "Site collection administrators". I have the buttons "Permission levels" and "Access request settings" but down to this there is nothing :(

Comment: What is your permission for this site collection?

Comment: I am Owner, they gave me every permissions